# Proper way to query DataContext using Group by that has fields with Nulls

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

I'm using Entity Framework,  And I'm querying the Data using a Group By clause.  In the Group by there are multiple columns that have to be used. Some of the columns can have nulls.  The issue is that when it comes back it has all the proper group counts but it does not add anything to the groups. So the Group is a Group of 0 items.    here is the code below.

```
 using (_context = new DbContext())
                {

                    var groups = await _context.vw_PersonItem
                    .AsExpandable()
                    .Where(x => x.PersonName != "")
                    .GroupBy(x => new
                    {
                        x.PersonName,
                        x.Addressline1,
                        x.State,
                        x.Zip,
                        x.FavoriteColor   //< This Can Be Null
                    })
                    .ToListAsync(); 




                  int uniqueCount = 1;

                    foreach (var grp in groups)   // <  It has groups with 0 items
                    {
                            uniqueCount++;

                    }
};
```

It doesn't throw an error, and it does count the number of grouped items properly but, where it finds a null in one of the Group By Fields, the Group has a count of 0?
Any Advice?

Comment: Not sure I'm understand your question. Do you want to remove empty groups? If so you can add .`Where(g => g.Count() > 0)` before `.ToListAsync()`

Comment: No, I don't want to remove them. The shouldn't be empty. Because there is is a Unique Combination in the data. it should be a group. of at least 1.

Comment: You are getting nulls in your return from the database.  You must have rows in the database with null rows.

Comment: The database has columns that allow nulls that are used in the Grouping.  But some of the groups are groups of 0.  Which is odd because to have a group. I would think there would have to be a group of at least 1.

Comment: What's the type of `FavoriteColor` property? If it is `string`, make sure it's not mapped as required, because doing so will lead to undefined behaviors and could somehow explain the issue.

Comment: I did a bunch more digging on this and the  issue with the Groups with 0 items, utmately ended up being that the Grouping was being done on the Object using Nulls, howerver the joins behind the scenes were using inner joins. So it would create  the proper number groups but wouldn't just not populate them because of the Referential Integrity on the Database.  I ended up creating a View with the Proper Relations for this and after handling the nulls as suggested below I have it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as example:

```
.GroupBy(x => x?.FavoriteColor ?? -1)
```

just modified answer to add another syntax option

```cs
GroupBy(x => x.FavoriteColor == null ? -1 : x.FavoriteColor)
```

Comment: This handled the Null Values and allowed me to give them meaningful values.

Answer (score 0):

I did a bunch more digging on this and the issue with the Groups with 0 items, utmately ended up being that the Grouping was being done on the Object using Nulls, howerver the joins behind the scenes were using inner joins. So it would create the proper number groups but wouldn't just not populate them because of the Referential Integrity on the Database. I ended up creating a View with the Proper Relations for this and after handling the nulls as suggested below I have it workin